# Avoid horizontal scroll bar with background video

Tags: css

I'm running a video in a background div.  It is meant to cover 100% of the screen but it is covering more than that and creating a horizontal scroll bar.  How do I fix this CSS so it covers the screen but doesn't give the scroll bar?  Many thanks in advance.

```
video#bgvid { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url() no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` on the parent

Comment: you would think, but that isn't working.  You can check it out on http://monster.hexiawebservices.co.uk

Comment: but setting max-width to 100% seems to have worked

Comment: looks like you've fixed it!

Comment: @HenryM you should add that as an answer, this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

add `overflow:hidden;` to element

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

**EDIT:**

```
video#bgvid {position: fixed;}
.about-us {overflow: hidden;}
```